# Firebase Storage getData cannot be awaited

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

My function ends before all data can be retrieved from the fire storage and returns empty.
How can I get the data before returning?

Code:

```
func listItem() -> [imageitem]{
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child("images/image")
        var array = [imageitem]()
        
        storageRef.listAll { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error")
                print(error)
            }
            print("storagereference")
                result?.items.forEach({ StorageReference in
                    print(StorageReference)
                    print(StorageReference.name)

                    
                    StorageReference.getData(maxSize: 5*1024*1024) {data, error in
                        if error == nil && data != nil{
                            if let image = UIImage(data: data!){
                                    let element =  imageitem(title: StorageReference.name, image: Image(uiImage: image))
                                    array.append(element)
                                    print(array)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            
            print("end",array)
        }
        return array
    }
```

Console:

```
storagereference
gs://proj-69776.appspot.com/images/image/gorilla.jpg
gorilla.jpg
gs://proj-69776.appspot.com/images/image/test.jpg
test.jpg
end []
[proj.ListView.imageitem(title: "test.jpg", image: SwiftUI.Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<__C.UIImage>))]
[proj.ListView.imageitem(title: "test.jpg", image: SwiftUI.Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<__C.UIImage>)), proj.ListView.imageitem(title: "gorilla.jpg", image: SwiftUI.Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<__C.UIImage>))]
```

adding an `await` before the `addData` gives me an error
`Cannot pass function of type '(StorageReference) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type`

Comment: Be careful when you mix closures with concurrency (async await) you need a "Continuation" Check out Meet async/await in Swift from #wwdc21
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return data that is loaded asynchronously with a `return` statement like that, because the `return` runs well before you ever append any element to the array. If you set breakpoints and run the code in a debugger you can most easily validate that.

Instead, you'll want to pass in a closure/callback or use a dispatch queue to get the value out of your function into the calling context.

For examples of how to do this, see:

- [Return image from asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628089/return-image-from-asynchronous-call)
- [Unable to assign value within a function in Firebase API callback block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778908/unable-to-assign-value-within-a-function-in-firebase-api-callback-block/42778959#42778959)
- [When I try to access my array outside of this function it appears to be empty.I t is something to do with an asynchronous call, any suggestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922977/when-i-try-to-access-my-array-outside-of-this-function-it-appears-to-be-empty-i)
- [Accessing Array Outside Closure in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015954/accessing-array-outside-closure-in-swift-3)
- [How to make synchronous operation with asynchronous callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388608/how-to-make-synchronous-operation-with-asynchronous-callback)
- [How to upload the profile image URL to firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675818/how-to-upload-the-profile-image-url-to-firebase-database/60678170#60678170)

Comment: Easier is to use the `async` variations of the APIs. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseStorage/Sources/AsyncAwait.swift#L31